# docker container links translating with extra information

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have a simple example set up, running a centos or ubuntu image I've discovered that all my symlinks inside of a mounted volume are broken.

given the directory structure

> **testsyms**
>   real
>   --one
>   --twoHundred
>   --three
>   syms
>   --one
>   --twoHundred
>   --three

and using the following docker command to start my container

`docker run -ti -v $HOME/testsyms/:$HOME/testsyms -w $HOME/testsyms`

I then do the following
inside the container :

```
[root@96b9af1cd545 testsyms]# ls -l **/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 games  0 Jan  8 06:00 real/one
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 games  0 Jan  8 06:03 real/three
-rw-r--r-- 1 501 games  0 Jan  8 06:00 real/twoHundred
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 games 11 Jan  8 06:00 syms/one -> l/one
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 games 19 Jan  8 06:03 syms/three -> ../real/three
lrwxr-xr-x 1 501 games 18 Jan  8 06:01 syms/twoHundred -> l/twoHundred
```

outside the container :

```
tam@tam-osx:testsyms$ ls -l **/*
-rw-r--r--  1 tam  staff   0 Jan  7 23:00 real/one
-rw-r--r--  1 tam  staff   0 Jan  7 23:03 real/three
-rw-r--r--  1 tam  staff   0 Jan  7 23:00 real/twoHundred
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tam  staff  11 Jan  7 23:00 syms/one -> ../real/one
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tam  staff  19 Jan  7 23:03 syms/three -> /Users../real/three
lrwxr-xr-x  1 tam  staff  18 Jan  7 23:01 syms/twoHundred -> ../real/twoHundred
```

I created the links one and twoHundred outside the container while I created link three inside the container. inside the container links one and TwoHundred are broken. outside the container link three is broken as you should be able to see from the above outputs.

**UPDATE**--
Base on the comments I tried to ssh into the docker machine and found that the links are both correct, and incorrect. Doing some digging I find that I have my shared folder `Users` in 2 places. I have a `/Users` directory and I have a `/mnt/hgfs/Users` directory. Here is the output of each directory

/Users/ :

```
docker@default:/mnt/hgfs$ ls -l /Users/boger/testsyms/**/*
-rw-r--r--    1 501      20               0 Jan  8 06:00 /Users/boger/testsyms/real/one
-rw-r--r--    1 501      20               0 Jan  8 06:03 /Users/boger/testsyms/real/three
-rw-r--r--    1 501      20               0 Jan  8 06:00 /Users/boger/testsyms/real/twoHundred
lrwxr-xr-x    1 501      20              11 Jan  8 06:00 /Users/boger/testsyms/syms/one -> l/one
lrwxr-xr-x    1 501      20              19 Jan  8 06:03 /Users/boger/testsyms/syms/three -> ../real/three
lrwxr-xr-x    1 501      20              18 Jan  8 06:01 /Users/boger/testsyms/syms/twoHundred -> l/twoHundred
```

/mnt/hgfs/Users/ :

```
docker@default:/mnt/hgfs$ ls -l /mnt/hgfs/Users/boger/testsyms/**/*
-rw-r--r--    1 501      20               0 Jan  8 06:00 /mnt/hgfs/Users/boger/testsyms/real/one
-rw-r--r--    1 501      20               0 Jan  8 06:03 /mnt/hgfs/Users/boger/testsyms/real/three
-rw-r--r--    1 501      20               0 Jan  8 06:00 /mnt/hgfs/Users/boger/testsyms/real/twoHundred
lrwxr-xr-x    1 501      20              11 Jan  8 06:00 /mnt/hgfs/Users/boger/testsyms/syms/one -> ../real/one
lrwxr-xr-x    1 501      20              19 Jan  8 06:03 /mnt/hgfs/Users/boger/testsyms/syms/three -> /Users../real/three
lrwxr-xr-x    1 501      20              18 Jan  8 06:01 /mnt/hgfs/Users/boger/testsyms/syms/twoHundred -> ../real/twoHundred
```

its worth noting they have the same pattern as what I showed about inside and outside the container. Below is my config for the vm for the shared folders

```
sharedFolder0.present = "true"
sharedFolder0.enabled = "true"
sharedFolder0.readAccess = "true"
sharedFolder0.writeAccess = "true"
sharedFolder0.hostPath = "/Users"
sharedFolder0.guestName = "Users"
sharedFolder0.expiration = "never"
sharedFolder0.followSymlinks = “TRUE”
sharedFolder.maxNum = "1"
```

To work around this it turns out I just need to mount a different folder. I tried starting docker with `-v /mnt/hgfs/Users/...` and it works without any issues. I would really like to know what I can do to set up my vm so this isn't a problem down the road for other developers on my team though. Is my best option really to just ignore the broken directory and mount a new one ?

Comment: do `docker-machine ssh name-of-machine` and check your symlinks there first. That should tell you is it a docker-machine level problem or container

Comment: Seems you're using Mac, how did you expose your host file system to docker VM? That file system share may cause problems.

Comment: @Fuxi I just checked this and sure enough the links are messed up at the vm level !

Comment: @Boynux I didn't do anything special, I'm just using the default shared folder set up in vmware

Comment: That's my point, there is a possibility that symlinks does not work properly in shared filesystem (and docker containers). Try to ssh into the docker vm and run command there on native vm filesystem.

Comment: after investigating ssh into the docker vm as suggested I've discovered something interesting. I'll reflect in in the question